# Is this a Visual Studio bug or a C++ compiler bug?

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, c++-cli, visual-studio-2019

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.6.

This is a CLR Project (.NET Framework 4.5).

I'm not sure about the origin of this bug, so I cannot fill in a bug report to its respective program.

I either found a bug on Visual Studio Community 2019 or in the C++ compiler.

I have a MyMediaPlayer.dll which has the `AxInterop.WMPLib.1.0.dll` and `Interop.WMPLib.1.0.dll` added in its References.

I added the MyMediaPlayer.dll in the References of my project and this piece of code is causing the compiler to complain with an internal error:

```
private: System::Double getMediaFileDuration(System::String^ fileName) {
        WMPLib::IWMPMedia^ mediainfo = WMPLib::WindowsMediaPlayerClass().newMedia(fileName);
        return mediainfo->duration;
}
```

When an internal error like this occurs the compiler stops working and it does not recognize anything I mean the code syntax in the header file also in the header files it's referenced from. That code works fine, I can build up my project and run with no exceptions. Just the compiler does not work when that piece of code is present.

`WMPLib::WindowsMediaPlayerClass` gets highlighted in red when mouse hovers on it it says internal error.

Comment: I don't think you are *writing* a compiler. But you could try to use  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` (and edit your C++ code with [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)...)

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that the circumflex can not bw used at that place in pure c++.

Comment: That is also not C++ code.

Comment: @gerum You're right, but this is a CLR project, the ^ (hat) is used as a pointer *. This is not the problem.

Comment: ...also, what is the error it reports? Throw the error message at a web search as well!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It's CLR VM which uses C++ compiler with /clr command. The only thing it reports when I put the mouse cursor on it is "Internal error".